# Double line breaks with Notepadd++

Tags: regex, replace, notepad++, line-breaks

I am preparing some Whatsapp chat logs for rendering out statistics and wordclouds. However my data every now and  then has double line-break artifacts which mess with log's formatting, I'm wondering how could I automate the fix.

```
13 Mar 18:51 - nicola: mainly he's crap
13 Mar 18:52 - Sebastian K: ... you didn't really dress it up
13 Mar 18:52 - nicola: and he has no natural grace like most cats 

well no i didn't lol
13 Mar 18:52 - nicola: you saw the last video
13 Mar 18:53 - Sebastian K: Stilton jumped onto that wall effortlessly while Ched almost killed himself yea...
```

Searched for and deleted empty lines (easy fix). However I'm still left with lines which break Date&Time formatting:

```
13 Mar 18:51 - nicola: mainly he's crap
13 Mar 18:52 - Sebastian K: ... you didn't really dress it up
13 Mar 18:52 - nicola: and he has no natural grace like most cats 
well no i didn't lol
13 Mar 18:52 - nicola: you saw the last video
13 Mar 18:53 - Sebastian K: Stilton jumped onto that wall effortlessly while Ched almost killed himself yea...
```

Goal format:

```
13 Mar 18:51 - nicola: mainly he's crap
13 Mar 18:52 - Sebastian K: ... you didn't really dress it up
13 Mar 18:52 - nicola: and he has no natural grace like most cats well no i didn't lol
13 Mar 18:52 - nicola: you saw the last video
13 Mar 18:53 - Sebastian K: Stilton jumped onto that wall effortlessly while Ched almost killed himself yea...
```

Maybe solution is in exploiting this rule: Line-breaks which I need to retain follow pattern:

```
TEXT *linebreak* 
NUMBER(begging of date column)
```

Pesky ones follow pattern:

```
TEXT *linebreak*
TEXT
```

How could I go about fixing it working with Notepad++ ?

Answer (score 1):

In the search and replace dialogue you can search for this pattern

```
\r\n(?!\d)
```

with Regular expression enabled and replace with nothing.

`\r\n` searches for a line break consisting of a CR and LF. Enable in Notepad++ the display of control characters to see what line break you have.

`(?!\d)` is [negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) assertion that is true, when there is no digit following. This works for your example, but can fail for some corner cases, you can the extend this to a pattern, e.g. `(?!\d{2}\s)` when the date is always a two digit day.